# Understanding ASN.1 Integer PER encoding

Tags: decode, wireshark, asn.1

Consider this Wireshark trace for a h225 Ras Registration Request (RRQ):

[image]

as you can see, Wireshark decodes `requestSeqNum` as 25601 but the byte presentation is 0x6400 which is 25600. I looked in the ASN.1 PER encoding rules, but I can't find the reason why the value would have to be increased with 1. My question, is wireshark decoding this correctly and if so, where can I find this in the spec?

ASN.1 code:

```
RequestSeqNum       ::= INTEGER (1..65535)
```

In fact, Wireshark consistently adds 1 to `requestSeqNum` for all h225 messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind,

found it in the [ASN.1 PER encoding rules spec](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.691-202102-I!!PDF-E&type=items):

> 11.5.7.3 (The two-octet case.) If the "range" has a value greater than or equal to 257 and less than or equal to 64K, then the value ("n" –
> "lb") shall be encoded in a two-octet bit-field (octet-aligned in the
> ALIGNED variant) as a non-negative- binary-integer encoding as
> specified in 11.3.

lb (Lower bound) is in this case 1 so that explains my question.
I was looking at the wrong place in the spec, I get headaches from reading specifications :)